# How to modify a button in tablelayout with a contextview in Android

Tags: android, button, text, contextmenu

I was wondering how to change the label of a button once I performed a long click on it, in Android, using a contextmenu.

I know how to generate a contextmenu with a long click, but I am not sure how to access the clicked button, view, in the onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) method.

Also, the button that is clicked is in a tableLayout, so I am not sure if I can use an AdapterContextMenuInfo instance variable either to access the view.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_edit:
        //change button's text
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_delete:
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_cancel:
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Any insight into how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `onContextItemSelected(...)` is called, android calls `onCreateContextMenu(...)`. If you override this method, you can save (to a local variable) the `View` that was passed in as a parameter (this is the `View` that was clicked). Then, in `onContextItemSelected(...)`, you can modify the text using the saved `View` Object.

For example:

```
View lastClickedView;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                               ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    lastClickedView = v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_edit:
        lastClickedView.setText("new button text");
        return true;
      case R.id.menu_delete:
        return true;
      case R.id.menu_cancel:
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findViewById(id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) to get a View object given an id, and then call [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) on it.

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.menu_edit:
    //change button's text
    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_edit);
    myButton.setText("new text");    
    return true;
  case R.id.menu_delete:
    return true;
  case R.id.menu_cancel:
    return true;
}
```